# I can't find why is my data not being displayed in firebase real time database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have debugged this and it seems to be correctly linked and all data is saved as it should but when comes time to add to the server it doesn't do anything ##

What are some things that I am doing wrong and what can I change for it to work? This is written in kotlin with a firebase real-time database and yes, I have changed the permissions in firebase to be a able to read and write

```
class AddItemToDataBasePage : AppCompatActivity() {    
   private lateinit var etName : EditText
   private lateinit var etBrand : EditText
   private lateinit var etType : EditText
   private lateinit var etPrice : EditText
   private lateinit var  etAmount: EditText
   lateinit var addBtn : Button
   private lateinit var dbRef : DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item_to_data_base_page)

        //Linking to var to buttons so we cab get the data
        etName = findViewById(R.id.addItemName)
        etBrand = findViewById(R.id.addItemBrand)
        etType = findViewById(R.id.addItemType)
        etPrice = findViewById(R.id.addItemPrice)
        etAmount = findViewById(R.id.addItemAmount)
        addBtn = findViewById(R.id.addItemButton)

        // DB Reference
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items")

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(){

            addingItems()
        }


    }

    private fun addingItems() {

        val name = etName.text.toString()
        val brand = etBrand.text.toString()
        val type = etType.text.toString()
        val price = etPrice.text.toString()
        val amount = etAmount.text.toString()


        if ( name.isEmpty() && brand.isEmpty() && type.isEmpty() && price.isEmpty() && amount.isEmpty()){

            Toast.makeText(this,"Please fill all areas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }
        if ( name.isNotEmpty() && brand.isNotEmpty() && type.isNotEmpty() && price.isNotEmpty() && amount.isNotEmpty()){

            val itemsData = ItemsDataModel(name,brand,type,price,amount)

            dbRef.child(name).setValue(itemsData).addOnSuccessListener {


                etName.text.clear()
                etBrand.text.clear()
                etType.text.clear()
                etPrice.text.clear()
                etAmount.text.clear()

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Item Added Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }.addOnFailureListener{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Failed To add Item",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }

        }

    }
}
```

These are my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
        // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1')
        // Add the dependency for the Firebase Authentication library
        // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
        // Also add the dependency for the Google Play services library and specify its version
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0'

}
```

This is the project gradle

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }


}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
```

Comment: I am trying to add data ( items ) into the real-time database so then I can read them and make a list of items and have the list update depending if I add more items or not

Comment: if you have more information you want to add to your question, there's an edit link under it that allows you to do so. This makes it more likely that folks will actually see that information.

Comment: If you get no error/failure message from `dbRef.child(name).setValue(itemsData)`, make sure that the `google-services.json` was downloaded *after* you created the database in the Firebase console. If you're not sure about that, re-download it and use the updated file in your project.

Comment: There is a bit of a logic error as well - the first test for "empty" requires _all_ the fields to be empty (because of the use of logical AND) when really the test should be for _any_ field empty (logical OR).  Then in the second test _all_ fields must be not empty (which is correct) - but that leaves the cases where some-but-not-all fields are empty which results in *nothing happening*.  And really you could make the first test an `else` of the second to reduce complexity.

Comment: Is any of the toast messages displayed? If yes, which one? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys the issue was not in my code but in the emulator that was not working as it should it was acting as if it did not have the internet to add the data to the database. I have not solved the emulator issue but my app was able to add items once I installed it on my physical device. Any tips on how to fix the emulator issue will be very helpful